# Add column header to HTML table (List to HTML table)

Tags: c#, html

Current code is working fine. However column headers are missing. In current example `NRO, NRO1, SNAME` are column headers.

I understand that `<th>` should be added to existing method but have hard times figuring out how?

```
  <tr>
    <th>NRO</th>
    <th>NRO1</th>
    <th>SNAME</th>
  </tr>
```

Here is List to HTML table method (found on this website):

```
    public static string GetMyTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params Func<T, object>[] fxns)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>\n");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>\n");
            foreach (var fxn in fxns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(fxn(item));
                sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I use it like this:

```
    var HTML = GetMyTable(duplicates, x => x.NRO, x => x.NRO1, x => x.SNAME);
```

---

I have tried to do it like this:

```
    public static string GetMyTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params Func<T, object>[] fxns)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>\n");
        sb.Append("<tr>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>NRO</th>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>NRO1</th>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>SNAME</th>\n");
        sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>\n");
            foreach (var fxn in fxns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(fxn(item));
                sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Is it possible to make a loop for headers so there will be no need to assign them for each table separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following code, if I understand you correctly.

```
public static string GetMyTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list,
    params Func<T, (object, string)>[] fxns)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>\n");
    sb.Append("<tr>\n");

    foreach (var fxn in fxns)
        sb.Append("<th>").Append(fxn(default).Item2).AppendLine("</th>");

    sb.Append("</tr>\n");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>\n");
        foreach (var fxn in fxns)
        {
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(fxn(item).Item1);
            sb.Append("</td>");
        }
        sb.Append("\n</tr>\n");
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var html = GetMyTable(duplicates,
    x => (x?.NRO, nameof(x.NRO)),
    x => (x?.NRO1, nameof(x.NRO1)),
    x => (x?.SNAME, nameof(x.SNAME))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are adding the headers inside the loop, just create them once, when you create your table tag.

```
    public static string GetMyTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params Func<T, object>[] fxns)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>\n");
        // this needs to be outside the loop
        sb.Append("<tr>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>NRO</th>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>NRO1</th>\n");
        sb.Append("<th>SNAME</th>\n");
        sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {

            sb.Append("<tr>\n");
            foreach (var fxn in fxns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(fxn(item));
                sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have figured it out already. However this means that this method will not work for any table as headers are specified in method itself. Is it possible to create a loop for headers as well?